# telerik nested grid issue

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

1.Here I am having a grid within a parent grid and there is a link button within the nested grid.

2.For the link button I need to use the item command event of the nested grid or I can use the item command of parent grid as well.

3.The issue is when I click on the link button within nested grid then item command event doesn’t get fired for the nestedgrid.But in case of parent grid its working fine.

4.I have tried handlers and item created event also to use handlers in code behind or in aspx.But nothing helped in getting me item command event hit for the nested grid.

5.Previously in case of repeaters there was one item command which was handling all the grids. I have tried different item command event for child and parent but it also didn’t work.

Edit: here's a code sample

```
Public Sub grd_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, _
                                                ByVal e As nsTelerik.GridCommandEventArgs) _
                                                Handles grdCollClaimLevel.ItemCommand, grdCollLineLevel.ItemCommand, _
                                              grdCollLineValues.ItemCommand, grdCollPartLevel.ItemCommand, _
                                              grdPTNClaimLevel.ItemCommand, _
                                               grdPTNLineLevel.ItemCommand, grdPTNLineValues.ItemCommand


        Dim uicCharMain As nsPTNWebContext.CharMainUIC
        Dim uicCollDetl As nsPTNWebContext.CollDetlUIC
        Dim uicPTNItem As nsPTNWebContext.PatternItemUIC

        Try

            Select Case e.CommandName
                Case c_sBtnChar

                    uicCharMain = New nsPTNWebContext.CharMainUIC()

                    With uicCharMain
                        .CharID = CStr(e.CommandArgument)
                        .Busns_Event_Cd = m_uicRsltMatc.BusEvent
                        .PTN_LOB_Cd = m_uicRsltMatc.LOB
                        .UserID = m_uicRsltMatc.UserID
                        .ModePTN = m_uicRsltMatc.ModePattern
                        .ModeChar = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeChar
                        .ModeColl = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeColl
                        .ModeRept = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeRept
                        .PageMode = nsPTNWebContext.CharMainUIC.enPageMode.View
                        .TabMode = m_uicRsltMatc.TabMode
                    End With

                    Me.PageState.Save()
                    Me.Navigation.AddMe(c_sCharMain)
                    Me.Navigation.Transfer(uicCharMain)

                Case c_sBtnColl

                    uicCollDetl = New nsPTNWebContext.CollDetlUIC( _
                        CStr(e.CommandArgument), _
                        m_uicRsltMatc.BusEvent, _
                        m_uicRsltMatc.LOB)

                    With uicCollDetl
                        .UserID = m_uicRsltMatc.UserID
                        .ModeColl = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeColl
                        .PageMode = nsPTNWebContext.CollDetlUIC.enPageMode.View

                        .ModePTN = m_uicRsltMatc.ModePattern
                        .ModeChar = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeChar
                        .ModeRept = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeRept
                        .BusEvent = m_uicRsltMatc.BusEvent
                        .LOB = m_uicRsltMatc.LOB
                        .TabMode = m_uicRsltMatc.TabMode
                    End With

                    Me.PageState.Save()
                    Me.Navigation.AddMe(c_sCollDetails)
                    Me.Navigation.Transfer(uicCollDetl)

                Case c_sBtnPattern

                    uicPTNItem = New nsPTNWebContext.PatternItemUIC(CStr(e.CommandArgument))

                    With uicPTNItem
                        .BusEvent = m_uicRsltMatc.BusEvent
                        .LOB = m_uicRsltMatc.LOB
                        .UserID = m_uicRsltMatc.UserID
                        .ModeChar = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeChar
                        .ModeColl = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeColl
                        .ModePattern = m_uicRsltMatc.ModePattern
                        .ModeRept = m_uicRsltMatc.ModeRept
                        .CharID = m_uicRsltMatc.CharID
                        .CollID = m_uicRsltMatc.CollID
                        .PageMode = nsPTNWebContext.PatternItemUIC.enPageMode.View
                        .TabMode = m_uicRsltMatc.TabMode
                    End With

                    Me.PageState.Save()
                    Me.Navigation.AddMe(c_sPatternItem)
                    Me.Navigation.Transfer(uicPTNItem)

            End Select

        Finally
            Cleanup(uicCharMain)
            uicCharMain = Nothing
            Cleanup(uicCollDetl)
            uicCollDetl = Nothing
            Cleanup(uicPTNItem)
            uicPTNItem = Nothing

        End Try
    End Sub
```

And here's the markup

```
        <tel:radgrid runat="server" id="grdPTNPartLevel" width="100%" autogeneratecolumns="false"
            horizontalalign="Justify">
            <mastertableview width="100%">
                <NestedViewTemplate>
                    <tel:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grdPTNPartValues" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        HorizontalAlign="Justify" OnItemDataBound="grdPTNPartValues_ItemDataBound">
                    </tel:RadGrid>
                    <tel:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grdPTNLineLevel" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        HorizontalAlign="Justify" OnItemDataBound="grdPTNLineLevel_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="grd_ItemCommand">
                        <MasterTableView Width="100%">
                            <NestedViewTemplate>
                                <tel:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grdPTNLineValues" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    HorizontalAlign="Justify" OnItemDataBound="grdPTNLineValues_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="grd_ItemCommand">
                                </tel:RadGrid>
                            </NestedViewTemplate>
                        </MasterTableView>
                    </tel:RadGrid>
                </NestedViewTemplate>
            </mastertableview>
        </tel:radgrid>
```

Comment: Some code would help illustrate the problem.  Can you post the markup for the entire grid?

Comment: Thanks, I just posted the markup

Comment: also this sample http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/threelevel/defaultcs.aspx can be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some of your code, I can't be quite sure on where this problem lies.  The first thing I'd try though is something similar to what telerik has in their API [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grddistinguishgridrowsinhierarchyonitemdatabound.html).  You're going to need to make sure you're working with the proper OwnerTable before doing anything with the command item.  Using something like this, determine that the item is for the right table, then you should have access to it.

```
 //identify to which table belongs the currently bound item
        if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name == "MyUniqueTableName")
       {
        //process requested operations
       }
```

**EDIT**

I see what you're trying to do.  I think you may be going about it the wrong way.  Take a look at the hierarchy section on telerik's [demo page here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/nestedviewtemplatedeclarativerelations/defaultcs.aspx).  It's very informative, and I had a 4-tier hierarchy working complete with some code behind in just a few hours and all with just 1 radgrid.

Comment: I hear ya, I just don't have the flexibility to change much of the approach on this particular project

Answer (score 0):

Hello in the nested view only you can bind one record, in order to get controls that are inside the nested view I use something like this.

```
protected void gvwData_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.NestedView )
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        HtmlGenericControl InfoDvi= (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("DivWithServerSideTagName");
    }
}
```